# Does a null SecurityManager check yield greater performance when doing doPrivs?

Tags: java, performance, java-security

I have seen the following pattern many times when doing operations that require special privilage (such as `Class.getClassLoader()`)

```
final Class<?> clazz = MyClass.class;

if(System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
  // Do the operation normally, since Java 2 Security is not enabled
  return clazz.getClassLoader();
} 
else {
  // Use a doPriv, since Java 2 Security is enabled
  return AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<ClassLoader>() {
    @Override
    public ClassLoader run() {
      return clazz.getClassLoader();
    }
  });
}
```

I'm assuming the benefit here is when Java 2 security is not enabled, the code avoids constructing the anonymous inner class, and avoids the extra method call to AccessController.doPrivilaged().

So, my question is:  
**Is an extra null check worth potentially avoiding construction of the anonymous `PrivilagedAction` object and extra doPriv call on the stack?**

The example I have shown is just a 1-liner, but there are more complex procedures as well that could follow this pattern, and I worry that maintaining the two sets of code is error-prone.
It would be great if the JVM optimized this automatically, but I don't know enough about the inner-workings of the JVM to know if/how much of a performance hit it is to always use a doPriv.

Comment: Nano-optimizations like this rarely matter.  Your application, network, database, etc. are more likely to be issues.  The only way to tell is to profile the application and get real data.  Anything else is guessing.

Comment: No. This is pure micro-optimization, so if you're writing this only for performance gains you should really learn what performance is in its core.